# Remove a Specific Part of The String In The Cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, replace, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upS2q.png)

Hi everyone,

I want to delete a specific part of the string in the cell. For example, I need a formula that will delete the "SEPETTE %5 İNDİRİM" string in the image.

Warning: the percentage changes in other cells.
For example:
1-SEPETTE %5 İNDİRİM
2-SEPETTE %15 İNDİRİM
3-SEPETTE %30 İNDİRİM

Input:19,95 TLSEPETTE %5 İNDİRİM18,95 TL
Output must be:19,95 TL18,95 TL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in C1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(B1:B, "SEPETTE %\d+ İNDİRİM", " "))
```